# Finding objects based on a string comparison with ActiveRecord and Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, string, activerecord, range

I have got an input string e.g. banana and am trying to find the corresponding object in the database. That object has a lower limit attribute and an upper limit attribute that include only the first letters. Their length is not defined. So the lower limit could be 'a' or 'ananas' and the upper limit could be 'b' or 'ban'. If the given input string starts with a letter that is in between the range, the following query works:

`scope :by_name, lambda {|input_string| where('lower_limit <= :input AND upper_limit >= :input', input: input_string) }`

But if the upper limit consists of the first letters of the search string the comparison fails because 'banana' > 'ban'.

How can the query be changed that it works?

I am using Ruby 1.9.3, Rails 3.2.3 and ActiveRecord 3.2.3.

Comment: Give us more complex example then 'banana'

Comment: My problem is that 'b' isn't greater than 'b' followed by any other character. The strings aren't any more complex than the samples offered below.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use input: input_string[0..1] instead

Comment: The length of the limit strings isn't defined. It could be 1 letter or 2, 3, 4, ... characters. One range could be 'a'-'ba' and the next could be 'bb'-'flag'. I do not know which range follows and it could happen that no directly following range exists.

Comment: So u have no solution of this goal?
May be better to start drawing tables with suspected input data and expected results?

Comment: The input data consists of a complete word (could be anything) and the expected result consists of all matching range objects (that could be 0..n). Something like the following tsql query would solve the problem at the upper boundary `SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE upper_limit = LEFT('banana', LEN(URL))` combined with my code snippet in the question. The problem is that I need a database independent solution.